# List of all String Constants from GDB

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm looking to analyze what information developers have put inside the source code as strings.

During the compilation process, is there a way to get GCC to output a list of all string constants used in a C++ programming. For example, if I write:

```
std::string result =  enterLog("The secret word is: elephant");
result =  enterLog("Checkpoint reached", "Now");
```

I would like to output

```
The secret word is: elephant
Checkpoint reached
Now
```

I would like to check to see if anyone has put the secret word in the code somewhere without having to check manually.

Comment: gdb isn't used during the compilation process, it's _only_ used manually. You can probably just add a rule to your build system to run `strings path-to-executable` for each executable file you build, though.

Comment: Many compilers can generate a *map* file which is a cross reference of all symbols and literals.  Search your compiler's documentation.

Comment: @Useless Yes, I intended GCC or G++, thank you

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks I feel this is close. Looking through documentation https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html I found that the Linker will generate a map using ` g++ main.cpp -Xlinker -Map=output.map` but the map file only contains functions and offsets and no string values at all. My gut is that the strings must be cataloged by the compiler and  and combined together by the linker in some way. However, I don't see options for either regarding how to extract the values of constants in c++